# For any positive integer $n$, is there an irreducible representation of degree $n$?

Tags: representation-theory

I want to prove a problem:
Prove that $Z(M_n(\Bbb{C}))=\{\lambda I\mid \lambda\in \Bbb{C}\}$.

If $M\in Z(M_n(\Bbb{C}))$,
let $\varphi:G\to GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ be an irreducible matrix representation of degee $n$,
then we have the following commutative diagram.
$$\Bbb{C}^n\stackrel{\varphi_g}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb{C}^n$$
$$M\downarrow~~~~~~~~~~~~\downarrow M$$
$$\Bbb{C}^n\stackrel{\varphi_g}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb{C}^n$$
Then by Schur's lemma,
$M=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in \Bbb{C}$.

I use an assertion in the proof:
for any positive integer $n$, there exists an irreducible representation of degree $n$.
But I am not sure that the assertion is true.

Comment: Is your $G$ the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?  You can check easily that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has an irreducible representation of degree $n$ given by the natural action of $n$-by-$n$-matrix on the $n$-dimensional vector space, essentially by what you wrote.  Also I don't understand why your argument proves $Z(M_n(\mathbb{C}))=\mathbb{C}I_n$.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks. You mean that let $\varphi:GL_n(\Bbb{C})\to GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ be the identity mapping.
Then $\varphi$ is a representation of degree $n$.
But how did you know that $\varphi$ is irreducible.

The statement of Schur's lemma which I had learned one is:
Let $\varphi$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ for $V$.
If a linear operator $T$ on $V$ satisfy $\varphi(g)T=T\varphi(g)$ for all $g\in G$, 
then $T=\lambda I$ with $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$.